# How to perform calculations in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is to calculate PAID DAYS in a month.It is done PAID DAYS=NoOfDaysInMonth-LEAVES.

For getting No of days i'm using

```
 declare @DATE datetime
 declare @NoOfDaysInMonth int
 set @DATE='2014-3-01'

 select @NoOfDaysInMonth= DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@DATE),0)))
 print @NoOfDaysInMonth
```

This returns 31 days.

Below is my previous query which is not working.

```
  *******  datediff(day, MONTH(getdate()), dateadd(month, 1, month(getdate())))-(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM  FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+@MONTH+''')) as [Paid Days] FROM  VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS'
```

In place of

```
 datediff(day, MONTH(getdate()), dateadd(month, 1, month(getdate())))
```

I need to pass the variable @NoOfDaysInMonth.

```
 @NoOfDaysInMonth-(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM  FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+@MONTH+''')) as [Paid Days] FROM  VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
```

After modifying my code is

```
SET @COMMANDS=@COMMANDS+' (SELECT TOTALLEAVESUSED FROM FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+@MONTH+''')) as [Total Leaves Used],(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+@MONTH+''')) as [Total UnPaid  Leaves], ( select @DaysInMonth -(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+@MONTH+'''))) as [Paid Days] FROM  VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS'
```

Comment: Now I don't understand what are you trying to do with this new piece of code: SET @COMMANDS=@COMMANDS+'... Do you want to get result in one variable, or what? It is getting too complicated with no reason.

Comment: leave all the other code... i changed the code as you told below....( select @DaysInMonth -(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+@MONTH+'''))) as [Paid Days] FROM  VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS                        but the procedure is not displaying and result(records)...its just showing "commands executed successfully" .

Comment: Is the number of left parenthesis equal to number or right parenthesis?

Comment: yes...i checked no problem in that

Comment: Try this: select @NoOfDaysInMonth -(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM FN_GETTOTALLEAVESFORANEMPLOYEE(VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.EMPLOYEEID,'''+@YEAR+''','''+‌​@MONTH+''') as [Paid Days] FROM VW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is fine. The last statement should be:

```
select @NoOfDaysInMonth-(SELECT TOTALUNPAIDLEAVES FROM ...) as Result
```

Keep in mind to execute this as a batch (this statement together with previous code, as a group of statements). Otherwise, the variable @NoOfDaysInMonth will be lost.